# Lambda function throws class not found exception when deployed with Jenkins generated zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, gradle, aws-lambda

I'm working on AWS Lambda function .I deploy it by uploading a zip file and source code (project) written in Java 8.

project is built using gradle. upon successful build, it generates the deployment zip.

this works perfectly fine when I deploy the locally generated zip in Lambda function.

**Working scenario:**

```
Zip generated through gradle build locally in workspace -> copied to AWS S3 
location -> specify the s3 zip path in Lambda upload/specify URL path field.
```

but when I generate the gradle build from jenkins , the zip which is generated is not working in the lambda function. it throws "class not found exception"

**Exception scenario:**

```
Zip generated through gradle in Jenkins -> copied to AWS S3 location -> 
specify the s3 zip path in Lambda upload/specify URL path field.

Class not found: com.sample.HelloWorld: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.HelloWorld
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

I suspected this could be the issue with file permissions of the content inside the zip file. i verfied this by comparing both the zip contents in a linux 
environment. I could see that files from the zip generated from jenkins lacks some permissions hence i handled permissons provision for the zip contents in 
my gradle build code.

```
    task zip(type: Zip) {

         archiveName 'lambda-project.zip'

         fileMode 0777

         from sourceSets.main.output.files.each { zipTree(it) }

         from (configurations.runtime) {

          into 'lib'

        }

    }
```

But still I'm getting the same error. I can see the file contents now have full permissions but still getting the same error.

**Note:**

1. Tried to make the deployment package as jar and tested. still getting same error.
2. I have configured the lambda handler configuration correctly. example: class name is "HelloWorld.java" and package name is com.sample then 
   my lambda handler configuration is com.sample.HelloWorld. I'm pretty confident about this point because with the same configuration 
   it works fine when zip generated locally
3. I have compared the zip contents (locally generated and jenkins generated ) could not see any difference in them

Comment: Is your directory structure in the root of the zip? Python Lambda functions have a limitation that the files should be in the root of the zip. I am not sure about Java though.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to access some resource, it can only be placed in a folder called tmp in the root of the lambda dir

Comment: can you post the output of `unzip -l file.zip` of the version generated with jenkins?

Comment: @hansaplast please find the result of unzip -l command below                              Archive:  lambda-project.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  02-13-2018 11:19   com/
        0  02-13-2018 11:19   com/sample/
     7464  02-13-2018 11:19   com/sample/HelloWorld.class
      819  02-13-2018 11:19   com/sample/HelloWorld$1.class
     2199  02-13-2018 11:19   application.properties
        0  02-13-2018 11:19   lib/
    41203  08-29-2017 17:14   lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

Comment: strange, this all looks correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directories inside the zip files were lacking permissions. I have tried by providing file permissions earlier but it worked after providing permissions for directories in gradle build.

dirMode 0777

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using serverless framework for lambda deployment, serverless framework help us to deploy lambda functions without much hassle. But if you want to setup CI, CD, monitoring and logging then you can refer to the book below.